# Minimizing Cost using Dijkstra's?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, dijkstra

I've spent a few more hours on a supposedly "Easy" practice question and think I'm in a spot to ask a more robust question. Would appreciate feedback.

The problem is still:

> You need to staff a desk so that one person is always there, for 24 hours straight. You have 6 people you can hire to do so but you want to minimize the cost. Anyone who works <=8 hours makes $15 an hour and anyone who works >8 hours makes $20/hr. What greedy algorithm can be used to minimize cost? (I.e. and figure out whether to hire 2 people for 12 hours each, 1 person for 24 hours, 3 people for 8 hours each, etc.)?

So I know that Dijkstra's is a "greedy" algorithm allows us to use weighted edges.

I understand the crux of the problem - that I could use Dijkstra's to find the set that minimizes the cost to cover a 24 hour shift. (For example, from the top level node, breaking off the child nodes into "1 person shift", "2 person shift", "3 person shift", "4 person shift", "5 person shift", "6 person shift" ... then in further child nodes, listing out every combination. The "weight" of the edges is the cost. I want to find the "cheapest" path But obviously that's unwieldy, since I'd have to list out every possible grouping (I.e. 5! and 6! security guards) and their cost.

```
In [4]:
shift = {}
shift["1_guard"] = {}
shift["2_guards"] = {}
shift["3_guards"] = {}
shift["4_guards"] = {}
shift["5_guards"] = {}
shift["6_guards"] = {}
#at each step we're doing a brute force attack to figure out ok ... if we have x guards, whats the breakdown of the total costs possible?
shift["1_guard"]["Shifts_Filled"] = (24 * 20)

shift["2_guards"]["1_hour_23_hours"] = ((15 * 1)+ (20 * 23))
shift["2_guards"]["2_hour_22_hours"] = ((15 * 2)+ (20 * 22))
shift["2_guards"]["3_hour_21_hours"] = ((15 * 3)+ (20 * 21))
shift["2_guards"]["4_hour_20_hours"] = ((15 * 4)+ (20 * 20))
shift["2_guards"]["5_hour_19_hours"] = ((15 * 5)+ (20 * 19))
shift["2_guards"]["6_hour_18_hours"] = ((15 * 6)+ (20 * 18))
shift["2_guards"]["7_hour_17_hours"] = ((15 * 7)+ (20 * 17))
shift["2_guards"]["8_hour_16_hours"] = ((15 * 8)+ (20 * 16))
shift["2_guards"]["9_hour_15_hours"] = ((15 * 9)+ (20 * 15))
shift["2_guards"]["10_hour_14_hours"] = ((15 * 10)+ (20 * 14))
shift["2_guards"]["11_hour_13_hours"] = ((15 * 11)+ (20 * 13))
shift["2_guards"]["12_hour_12_hours"] = ((15 * 12)+ (20 * 12))
#you dont need to do more than this because it will be one of these combos (it doesnt matter which guard works which shift)

shift["3_guards"]["1_hour_1_hour_22_hours"] = ((15 * 1) + (15 * 1) + (20*22)
#fill in for every combination of hours 3 guards could have
                                               
shift("4_guards")["1_hour_1_hour_1_hour_20_hours"] = ((15 * 1) + (15 * 1) (15 * 1) + (20*22)
#fill in for every combination of hours 3 guards could have

def find_lowest_cost_node(costs):
    lowest_cost = float("inf")
    lowest_cost_node = None
    # Go through each node.
    for node in costs:
        cost = costs[node]
        # If it's the lowest cost so far and hasn't been processed yet...
        if cost < lowest_cost and node not in processed:
            # ... set it as the new lowest-cost node.
            lowest_cost = cost
            lowest_cost_node = node
    return lowest_cost_node
start_time = time.perf_counter()

# Find the lowest-cost node that you haven't processed yet.
node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)
# If you've processed all the nodes, this while loop is done.
while node is not None:
    cost = costs[node]
    # Go through all the neighbors of this node.
    neighbors = shift[node]
    for n in neighbors.keys():
        new_cost = cost + neighbors[n]
        # If it's cheaper to get to this neighbor by going through this node...
        if costs[n] > new_cost:
            # ... update the cost for this node.
            costs[n] = new_cost
            # This node becomes the new parent for this neighbor.
            parents[n] = node
    # Mark the node as processed.
    processed.append(node)
    # Find the next node to process, and loop.
    node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)

print("Cost from the start to each node:")
print(costs)

print(time.perf_counter() - start_time, "seconds")
dijkstras_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
                                                      
# the costs table
infinity = float("inf")
costs = {}
costs["1_guard"] = 
costs["2_guards"] = 
costs["3_guards"] = 
costs["4_guards"] = infinity


# the parents table
#need help here
parents = {}
parents[""] = "NYC"
parents[""] = "NYC"
parents[""] = "NYC"
#all the ones below a certain threshold should have None*
parents[""] = None


processed = []
```

Am I going about this the right way? Feedback on my code would be really helpful.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have a lot of sense. You need 3 persons for 8 hours each (or more people for less hours, doesn't matter). What kind of graph fo you need to search to find that?

Comment: Remember to give feedback on past answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Dijkstra is necessarily the most useful here, since it yields the lowest cost path from A to B. Then again, if you really wanted to use it, you could let the intermediate nodes denote state, i.e. node G denotes the state `(08:00, 00:00)`, after having planned 08:00 up till 8AM where the current guard started at midnight. That way, the optimal path would be

`(00:00, 00:00) -> (01:00, 00:00) -> ... -> (08:00, 00:00) -> (09:00, 08:00) -> ...`

What you're doing then is actually *dynamic programming*, where you split the problem into smaller sub-problems and solve those to optimality.

Now, I played with your code a little with the new states I mentioned above. That reduces the search space to only ~325 nodes. You were actually very well on your way, just the part about parents I didn't get (and didn't need). Instead, I use a dictionary with tuple keys, and let the value denote the cost.

```py
infinity = float("inf")

nodes = {
    (current_hour, last_guard_started_hour): infinity
    for current_hour in range(25)
    for last_guard_started_hour in range(25)
    if last_guard_started_hour <= current_hour
}
start = current = (0, 0)
nodes[start] = 0
processed = []
```

Then, if you look at it like a square (x, y)-grid, the neighbours are the nodes at `(x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y + 1)`, unless you're at the border.

```py
def find_neighbours(current_node):
    current_hour, last_guard_started_hour = current_node
    
    # Neighbours are when either the guard started earlier/later or the current
    # hour progresses/regresses
    neighbours = []
    if current_hour > 0 and last_guard_started_hour != current_hour:
        neighbours.append((current_hour - 1, last_guard_started_hour))
    if current_hour < 24:
        neighbours.append((current_hour + 1, last_guard_started_hour))

    if last_guard_started_hour > 0:
        neighbours.append((current_hour, last_guard_started_hour - 1))
    if last_guard_started_hour < current_hour:
        neighbours.append((current_hour, last_guard_started_hour + 1))

    return neighbours
```

You can then gradually update nodes knowing the solution *until* the current guard started was optimal, so not needing to re-calculate that.

```
def get_cheapest_for_hour(hour):
    candidates = { n: nodes[n] for n in nodes
                   if n[0] == hour }

    # Get the entry with the lowest cost, but also prefer longer shifts
    node = min(candidates, key=lambda k: (nodes[k], k[1]))
    return node

def set_cost(node):
    hour, last_guard_started_hour = node
    if hour == 0 and last_guard_started_hour == 0:
        return

    cost = 0
    current_guard_hours_worked = hour - last_guard_started_hour

    # If the current guard starts just now, we get the cheapest solution for the
    # previous hour and add wages to that
    if current_guard_hours_worked == 0:
        nodes[node] = nodes[get_cheapest_for_hour(hour - 1)] + 15
        return
        
    if current_guard_hours_worked > 8:
        cost += current_guard_hours_worked * 20
    else:
        cost += current_guard_hours_worked * 15

    cost += nodes[(hour - current_guard_hours_worked, hour - current_guard_hours_worked)]
    nodes[node] = cost
```

Now this function I left the same, I think it's very smart!

```py
def find_lowest_cost_node():
    lowest_cost = infinity
    lowest_cost_node = None
    # Go through each node.
    for node in nodes:
        cost = nodes[node]
        # If it's the lowest cost so far and hasn't been processed yet...
        if cost < lowest_cost and node not in processed:
            # ... set it as the new lowest-cost node.
            lowest_cost = cost
            lowest_cost_node = node
    return lowest_cost_node
```

And here I simplified the code a bit to do without the parents

```py
while current is not None:
    cost = nodes[current]
    # Go through all the neighbours of the current node
    for n in find_neighbours(current):
        # Update their costs
        set_cost(n)
    
    processed.append(current)
    current = find_lowest_cost_node()

print("Cost from the start to each node:")
print(nodes)

print(f"Optimal schedule cost: {nodes[(24, 24)]}")
print("The optimal schedule is:")

node = (24, 24)
while True:
    hour, last_guard_started_hour = node
    current_guard_hours_worked = hour - last_guard_started_hour

    node = get_cheapest_for_hour(hour - current_guard_hours_worked)
    if node[0] == 0:
        break

    print(f"From {node[1]}:00 to {node[0]}:00")
```

Now, I haven't included the maximum of 6 guards, but you could obviously do that by extending the tuple to be `(current_hour, last_guard_started_hour, number_of_guards_used)`. Good luck!